# different EF containers that share the same connection string

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

I have an application that executes raw stored procedures against a large SQL 2008 database. The application is using custom database layer that I would like to convert to EF5 but still execute stored procedures. I would like to create different .edmx files that logically group stored procedures. For example, Users.edmx would contain functionality related to users, while Orders.edmx would contain functionality related to orders. However, I want both to point to the same connection string since they point to the same database. Can that be done without creating separate entry in app.config file? I would like to avoid the following:

```
<add name="Users" connectionString="metadata=res://*;*****;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="Orders" connectionString="metadata=res://*;*****;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Also, if this can be done and I have code that calls multiple stored procedures from different containers within `TransactionScope`, will Entity Framework attempt to use MSDTC coordinator even if they use the same connection?

Thanks in advance!